# distinctUnionOfObjects not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, nspredicate, distinct-values

I have created simple XCTest to test distinctUnionOfObjects. All the test cases are passing except one which is isKindOfClass (Last XCTAssertTrue). Any idea why it's changing the class when you do distinctUnionOfObjects.

```
- (void)testUsersPredicate
{
         NSArray *usersBeforePredicate = [[self userData] users];
         XCTAssertEqual([usersBeforePredicate count] , 34u, @"We need 34");
         XCTAssertTrue([[usersBeforePredicate lastObject] isKindOfClass:[ICEUsersModelObject class]], @"Object is not ICEUsersModelObject class");

         NSString *distinctUsersKeyPath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.%@", @"userName"];
         NSArray* usersAfterPredicate = [usersBeforePredicate valueForKeyPath:distinctUsersKeyPath];

         XCTAssertEqual([usersAfterPredicate count] , 30u, @"We need 30");
         XCTAssertTrue([[usersAfterPredicate lastObject] isKindOfClass:[ICEUsersModelObject class]], @"Object is not ICEUsersModelObject class");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the right key path on your `distinctUnionOfObjects` is `userName`, the `-valueForKeyPath`: call will return an `NSArray` of distinct userNames (not user objects).

From Apple's [KVC Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/CollectionOperators.html):

> The @distinctUnionOfObjects operator returns an array containing the distinct objects in the property specified by the key path to the right of the operator.

Change the last test case to check for `[NSString class]` and it should pass.

**Alternatives**

*Using equality:*

If the `userName`property is supposed to serve as a unique identifier, you could enforce that by overriding `-isEqual:` and `-hash`on the user object to reflect this:

```
- (BOOL)isEqual:(id)object {
    return ([object isKindOfClass:self.class] && [object.userName isEqual:self.userName]);
}

- (NSUInteger)hash {
    return self.userName.hash;
}
```

This can benefit your overall model design and opens up a lot of additional options, like this one that obtains a collection of distinct users reg. userName in one line - `NSSet` is very fast when used for this:

```
NSArray *uniqueUsers = [[NSSet setWithArray:users] allObjects];
```

- **Note:** I re-used the hashing function of `NSString` for the user hash, which has a subtle pitfall; `-[NSString hash]` only guarantees uniqueness for strings of up to 96 characters! This is not in the docs and took me almost a day to track down in production code. (see Apple's implementation of [CFString.c](http://opensource.apple.com/source/CF/CF-855.14/CFString.c) - search for `__CFStrHashCharacters`)

*Using NSPredicate:*

Here's a, let's say, 'creative' solution that uses a predicate. However, some kind of iteration is needed, because the predicate condition would otherwise have to be a function of its own result:

```
NSMutableArray *__uniqueUsers = [NSMutableArray array];
[[users valueForKeyPath:@"@distinctUnionOfObjects.userName"] enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id name, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    NSArray *uniqueUser = [users filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithBlock:^BOOL(id user, NSDictionary *bindings) {
        return [user.userName isEqual:name];
    }]];
    if (uniqueUser.count > 0)
        [__uniqueUsers addObject:uniqueUser.lastObject];
}];
NSArray *uniqueUsers = [NSArray arrayWithArray:__uniqueUsers];
```

It obtains a collection of unique userNames, iterates over it, selects exactly one user for each name and adds that to the output array.

Comment: So what do I need to do to get distinct object for the userNames ? Is there any way to get using NSPredicate ?

Comment: @AAV I've updated the answer with some examples I thought you might like.

Answer (score 1):

You test has no sense. You can't use `distinct` in this way because as `@mvanellen` told you, you should change the class in `NSString` due the fact that you are searching for distinct `username`.

You instead are **trying to get the list of objects considering distinct username**, but it is conceptually wrong. You should try to get the list of the username if you want, but not of the entire objects.

Consider to have in your array:

```
ITEM 1: aav / otherValue1

ITEM 2: aav / otherValue2

ITEM 3: matteo / otherValue3
```

for sure the function would return `ITEM 3`, but being a `distinct` query, which from `ITEM 1` and `ITEM 2` should it takes?

Think about this ;)

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And Yes I am thinking conceptually wrong. So what do I need to do for "get the list of objects considering distinct username". Can I use NSPredicate ?

Comment: No no. The problems is this. You shouldn't want to do this. Explain your situation.  Why do you need this? For what? How is possible that is not important if the function return you item 1 or item2 that are completely different except for the username?